# TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not an Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes

Tags: discord.js

I have a code where if mutes a mentioned person by giving it a role with no permissions but then I can't assign the role

Here's the code

```
      try{
    muterole = message.guild.roles.create({
        data: {
        name: 'muted',
        color: 'BLUE',
        permissions:[0]
      }
    })
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
    message.channel.send("An error occured logs were sent to the dev")
  }
  message.mentions.members.first().roles.add(muterole.id);
```

Any help is apreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
message.guild.roles.create({
    data: {
        name: "Muted",
        color: "BLUE",
        permissions: []
    }
}).then(role => {
    message.mentions.members.first().roles.add(role).catch(error => {message.channel.send("Couldn't add the role."); console.error(error)});
}).catch(error => {message.channel.send("An error occured, logs were sent to the developer."); console.error(error)});
```